# Question on two isomorphic simple algebraic extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let F be a field. Suppose that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two algebraic elements over F such that $F(\alpha)$ is isomorphic to $F(\beta)$. What is the relation between $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: There is not going to be any relation other than "$F(\alpha) \cong F(\beta)$".  Why do you think there should be anything more that could be said?

Comment: I think there may be something between minimal polynomials of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. For example, is it possible that there is transformation from one polynomial to the other? By saying transfromation I mean : Let $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ be two polynomials with same degree, transformation is $x=u(y)$ such that $f(u(y))=g(y)$.

Comment: I do not know what kind of "transformation" $u$ you have in mind, but it almost never is a polynomial because it'd have to have degree $1$. Take $\alpha$ to be a root of $x^3-18x-6$ and $\beta$ to be a root of $x^3-36x-78$. Is $\mathbf Q(\alpha) \cong \mathbf Q(\beta)$? It is not obvious at first glance how to figure this out (assuming you do not know algebraic number theory), and I have given you the two polynomials.

Comment: Yes, I know nothing about algebraic number theory. Could you help me to figure this out? By the way, if I need to figure out when $Q(\alpha)\cong Q(\beta)$, what information of algebraic number theory should I know? Can you recommend some textbooks a? Thanks.

Comment: There is no tidy simple answer to the question you posted. If you want to ask a different question then post it as a separate question and say what your background is in abstract algebra.

Comment: Thanks. There is one of my assignment which is :Find a 3 dimensional extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that it is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{b})$ for all $b\in \mathbb{Q}$. I think $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^{3}+5x^{2}+5x+5)$ may be one of those fields, but don't know how to prove.

Comment: Do you know *any* invariants of field extensions besides their degree? You have said absolutely nothing about your background or your mysterious course.

Comment: I learned abstract algebra before, using Herstein's Topics in Algebra. Now I am reading Morandi's Field and Galois Theory. The question I just asked is from this book. Orginal question is that: Give an example of a field extension $K/F$ with $[K:F]=3$ but with $K\neq F(\sqrt[3]{b})$ for any $b\in F$.

Comment: So you know Galois theory?

Comment: Oh, thanks. I only have to find a Galois extension $Q(\alpha)$, then $Q(\alpha)\neq Q(\sqrt[3]{b})$ for all $b\in F$, since $Gal(Q(\sqrt[3]{b}))=1$.

Comment: Yes, but that's kind of redundant. No cubic field of the form $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{b})$ is Galois over $\mathbf Q$. If you know about discriminants of field extensions (well-defined up to a nonzero square factor) then that would give another approach, since the discriminant of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{b})$ can be calculated by well-known formulas.

Comment: @KCd Thanks for your help. I find there is chapter in which it discuss discriminant. I will read that part. Could you introduce me a textbook of algebraic number theory?